# Login attempts and error handling in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to fix a login problem but I cannot find a solution. When both login and pass fail, an error message starts a countdown without letting the user manifest another opinion.

**QUESTION 1:** Can anyone please make the necessary corrections without altering too much the given code structure and explain?

**QUESTION 2:** What code would turn the "User1" text into bold at the moment the access is granted?

**QUESTION 3:** What command would disable the "X" on the top right-hand corner of the msg form?
Thank you in advance

Here it is what I could do  
 
     ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨

```
Private Sub BtOK_Click()
Dim User1 As String
Dim count As Integer
count = 3

MM:

If EDBoxlogin.Value = "admin" And EDBoxpass.Value = "1234" Then
   User1 = Application.UserName

   MsgBox "welcome" & User1 & " !", vbExclamation, "Access Granted"
   Sheets("Plan1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
   Unload Me
Else
    If EDBoxlogin.Value = "" Or EDBoxpass.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Please, fill in the fiels 'login' and 'pass'", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Access denied : incomplete information"
    Else
        If count >= 0 Then
           MsgBox "Login and pass are incorrect! You have " & count & " more trial(s)", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Access denied"
           EDBoxlogin.Value = "" And EDBoxpass.Value = ""
           ' I want to delete previous text in the editbox fields
           count = count - 1
           GoTo MM
        Else
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really need to know which user is opening the workbook, consider using Excel's built-in password security function.  Also, you should encrypt the contents of the file also using Excel's built-in functions, or anyone can open the file with a text editor and find the userID and password listed in your code.

If you must use a login form, and I've also had to do so in the past, the following code builds on what you did by adding a user list to a hidden worksheet `Users`.  Column A in that sheet needs to be the user names, B contains the passwords.  This worksheet also uses cell `D1` to track failed login attempts.  Using variables in code for this sort of thing is tough ... you have to make them `Public` and if there are any errors when running code, it will lose its value, then bad things can happen.

The code also references another sheet, `SplashPage`.  This allows you to hide `Project1` when the user exits the workbook.  The code I wrote handles the hide/unhide process when the file is opened or closed.

I don't know a way to turn off the close box in a user form.  I've added code to reject the login if a user does that.

Happy coding.

```
'Module: frmLogin
Private Sub BtOK_Click()
    Dim User1 As String
    Dim Passwd As Variant

    Sheets("Users").Range("D2").Value = False
    User1 = EDBoxlogin.Value
    Passwd = getPassword(User1)

        If User1 <> "" And Passwd <> "" And EDBoxpass.Value = Passwd Then
            Sheets("Users").Range("D2").Value = True
            MsgBox "Welcome " & User1 & "!", vbExclamation, "Access Granted"
            With Sheets("Plan1")
                .Visible = xlSheetVisible
                .Activate
            End With
            Sheets("SplashPage").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            Unload Me
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value = Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value - 1
            If Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Login and pass are incorrect! You have " & Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value & _
                    " more trial(s)", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Access denied"
                EDBoxpass.Value = ""
                With EDBoxlogin
                    .Value = ""
                    .SetFocus
                End With
                ' I want to delete previous text in the editbox fields
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

    UserForm_Terminate
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    If Sheets("Users").Range("D2").Value <> True Then
        MsgBox "Login cancelled, goodbye!"
        doWorkbookClose
    End If
End Sub

'Module: ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    doWorkbookClose
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value = 3
    With Sheets("SplashPage")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
    Sheets("Plan1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("Users").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    frmLogin.Show
End Sub

'Module: Module1
Function getPassword(strVarib As String) As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set sht = Sheets("Users")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A:A")

    r = WorksheetFunction.Match(strVarib, rng, 0)
    getPassword = sht.Cells(r, 2).Value
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    getPassword = Empty
End Function
Sub doWorkbookClose()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("SplashPage")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
    Sheets("Plan1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("Users").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

[begin Q&A]

Luiz, I've answered your edits below.

'Q: What Passwd does?

```
'Module: frmLogin
....
Passwd = getPassword(User1)
```

A: It gets the password value matching the value of `User1`.  Here's the whole function for context:

```
Function getPassword(strVarib As String) As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set sht = Sheets("Users")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A:A")

    r = WorksheetFunction.Match(strVarib, rng, 0)
    getPassword = sht.Cells(r, 2).Value
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    getPassword = Empty
```

If `User1` does not exist then `WorksheetFunction.Match` throws an error and code execution will jump to `ErrorHandler:`.

'Q: Does Empty mean that the cell is not with zeros or spaces, but completely blank instead?

A: `Empty` refers to a `Variant` variable type that is set to its default value.  `getPassword` could just as easily return the boolean `False` or integer `0` because those are the default values for those types.  It's actually not strictly necessary to set `getPassword` to anything here ... it's just my personal practice to be explicit.

Since `IsEmpty(celFoo)` is a valid test for whether a cell is empty or not, you might want to return `False` instead of `Empty` to avoid ambiguity.

'Q: Can you explain these two lines below in detail?

```
Set sht = Sheets("Users")
Set rng = sht.Range("A:A")
```

A: It's just habit.  The alternative would be to elminate those variable assignments and rewrite this line:

```
r = WorksheetFunction.Match(strVarib, rng, 0)
```

as:

```
r = WorksheetFunction.Match(strVarib, Sheets("Users").Range("A:A"), 0)
```

which is messier to type.  Especially if we're going to be doing other things on that sheet with that range in the same routine.  Which we are in the next block of code ...

'Q: Important to explain these three lines below in detail too [why 0?, To where (r,2) points to?]

```
r = WorksheetFunction.Match(strVarib, rng, 0)
getPassword = sht.Cells(r, 2).Value
Exit Function
```

A: To review, worksheet `Users` contains user IDs in column A, and their passwords in column B.  There can be as many users as there are rows in a worksheet.
- `rng` is column A as set above.
- `0` means find an exact match for strVarib and throw an error if not match is found.
- If we find a match, `r` will be set to the row number where the value in column A is equal to our input parameter, `strVarib`.
- So, `sht.Cells(r, 2).Value` is the password value in column B (column 2) for the UserID.

'Q: Why the need to call a splashpage? What it contains?

A: You don't necessarily need one, but if you really want to secure your workbook it's good practice.  Let's say that it contains sensitive information that you don't want unauthorized user to see.  At the very least you would:

- Encrypt the worbook using native Excel functionality.
- Password protect your VBA project using native functionality.  This keeps savvier users from reading your code and making the `xlSheetVeryHidden` sheets `Users` and `Plan1` visible to their prying eyes.
- Now, you can't hide all sheets in a workbook at the same time, at least one needs to be visible at any given time ...
- ... so I've created a third sheet called `SplashPage` that doesn't contain any sensitive information.  And that means I can hide all of the other worksheets until the user enters a valid UserID and password in `frmLogin`.

`SplashPage` can contain whatever you want.  You can call it whatever you want.  Typically, mine says something like:

```
Welcome to the Enemies List Application!
Only authorized users may access this workbook.

If you're seeing this page and no login form is visible
it means you've disabled the macros in this workbook.
Please make sure macro security is set to "Medium"
then close Excel entirely, reopen this file
and select "Enable Macros" when prompted.

If you attempt to view or modify this file without proper 
authorization you will be added to the list herein.

-[Signed] Richard M. Nixon
```

A really really secure workbook would not contain the users and passwords in a hidden sheet.  In fact, I *never* do this.  Most of my apps are database driven, and I authenticate users against both the domain and a custom table in the application database.  This effectively keeps anyone from using it unless they're onsite and connected to the network.  I also usually flush all the data from the relevant worksheets when the user closes the workbook to a) keep the file size smaller and b) keep sensitive data from being stored in it and taken offsite.  But that's beyond the original scope of your question.

'Why is [the following] necessary? What is being saved? Purpose?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
```

A: There are two scenarios for closing the application: 1) a failed login attempt and 2) a successful login by a user who has finished making changes.

Take case (2) first.  We want to hide all the sensitive information before closing so that the next person who opens the file only sees `SplashPage` and the login form.  We know the user is closing the workbook because we have this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module `BeforeClose` event script:

```
'Module: ThisWorkbook
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    doWorkbookClose
End Sub
```

All it does is call this subroutine in `Module1`:

```
Sub doWorkbookClose()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("SplashPage")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
    Sheets("Plan1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("Users").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Since our close routine makes changes to the workbook to hide sensitive information, those changes need to be saved.  If `ThisWorkbook.Save` wasn't there, Excel would prompt the user if they wanted to save "their" changes.  Which is annoying at best, confusing at worst, because most users will have already pressed "Save" before closing.  And if we give them the option here now to close without saving, then we run the risk of all those sensitive worksheets we've just made `xlVeryHidden` visible to the next user.  And that next user could be a bad guy who knows how to disable macros (or anyuser who simply has macro security set above `Medium`) which means that the following code wouldn't run:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Users").Range("D1").Value = 3
    With Sheets("SplashPage")
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With
    Sheets("Plan1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("Users").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    frmLogin.Show
End Sub
```

which is my semi-paranoid-self trying to make it as sure as possible that the next user opening this file doesn't see something I don't want them to.

Note that none of this secuity is bomb-proof.  It will lock out most average Excel users that you don't want in it, but someone who knows more about VBA than I do could probably find a way in.

Yes, that was an invitation. :)

Comment: Hello, thank you Brandon for your help! Indeed it was an interesting solution. However, for learning purposes, could you please give an explanation of the fragments of code marked with a quotation mark? (See above)

Comment: I tacked on your questions as an edit below the original answer.  Also note I changed some lines of code in `frmLogin` to fix a bug in the failed login routine.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for all your efforts and detailed explantion. I have understood and I will now put into practice :) Kind regards !