# How Do I Capture The User Who Tries To Unprotect A Worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to capture the user, who tries to unprotect a worksheet, via VBA.

i.e. a user opens a workbook, selects a worksheet, it's password protected and he/she tries to unprotect it, this instance of who the user is who is trying to unprotect the worksheet is what I am looking for. 
Can someone advise if this possible; and if so, help provide the coding needed to achieve this please?

I have searched the forum for this question but had no success.

I am using Microsoft Office 2010 and I use VBA at a beginner level.

Thanks in advance.
Hash

Answer (score 0):

The only way to detect password attempts would be to create your own authentication (and logging or notification) process with a list of userid's & passwords.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816685/8112776) is one method to do that, but even then, a person could just make a 2nd copy of the workbook and you wouldn't even know.

Note that Office document passwords are (sadly) remarkably easy to bypass, to anyone who knows how to use Google. [Here](https://youtu.be/YC2GyeY6ZdE) is one method.

If you need to make sure a file is 100% protected you'll need to use [3rd-party encryption software](https://www.google.ca/search?q=encrypt%20files%20free%20windows&num=100&dcr=0&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y).

Comment: Excel sheet protection after 2007 is aes-128 so quite a bit stronger. VBA protection though is still fairly weak.